# Reinit Datatables with plugin?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatables initialized by other JS (I can't add any option to initializing function), and now I want to add a rowReorder plugin. Can I do that without destroying it and creating again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doable *if* the DataTable instance is stored in a accessible variable. Example: If that "other JS" have passed the instance to a global variable called `table` then you can

```
new $.fn.dataTable.RowReorder( table, {} );
```

`{}` is an object literal holding options for rowReorder, passing an empty literal is the same as `rowReorder: true`.

Comment: I can get it by:
    
    var table = $($.fn.dataTable.tables()[0]).DataTable(); (first element)
    
and.. it works, thanks!

Comment: @K.A.T.,  great solution! But you can reduce that to something like `new $.fn.dataTable.RowReorder( $.fn.dataTable.tables(), {} );` the first param can be an array of instances as well (and it dont care if you have a `dataTable`/jQuery or `DataTable`/API instance, see example **http://jsfiddle.net/82dbpkj1**

Comment: ok, thanks for advice, but I still need to change 'row-reordered' function for this dt;) but very much thanks;)